# How to fake a url?

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url as `http://mydomain.com/levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d`.

I need to make fake url of above url. When I type a url `http://mydomain.com/medium` in address bar of browser, request needs to go in  url `http://mydomain.com/levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d`, but address bar will need to show this url `http://mydomain.com/medium` itself.

How can we do this with .htaccess file?

EDIT:

I tried with

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^medium.*$ /levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But this will redirect to original url `/levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d` and showing this url instead of `/medium` url in address bar.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule medium.php(.*)$ levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think `^medium$` is what he meant!

Comment: Here `/medium` is dummy url, only make user easy to type, show a simple url in address bar.